# can CGMainDisplayID() be used with iOS?

Tags: iphone

Hello I am new to developing applications in iPhone.
Can some one clarify my doubt whether CGMainDisplayID() be used to get the ID of main display in iPhone. CGMainDisplayID() belongs to mac references library and it is used to get the ID of main display in mac. will it work for iPhone as well in the same manner?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out UIScreen and +mainScreen.